# Nivo slider reloads the image every time

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, nivo-slider

Nivo slider reloads the image every time it slides that image, works perfectly on localhost , but when i host it in server(apache) it behaves this way. i calling nivo slider through a function call (once) not when the body loads. dont confuse with ajax call. called this function only once the button is clicked and called the slider on the data retrieved from the request.

```
    function call_to_refresh_results()
    {
$.ajax({
    url:url_to_send,
    async:true,
    success:function(data){ 
    $("#fetched_view_for_event").empty();

    $("#fetched_view_for_event").html(data);
    $("#slider").nivoSlider({
   directionNav: false, // Next & Prev navigation
    directionNavHide: true, // Only show on hover
    controlNav: false, // 1,2,3... navigation
    controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
    pauseOnHover: true, // Stop animation while hovering
    manualAdvance: false, // Force manual transitions
    prevText: 'Prev', // Prev directionNav text
    nextText: 'Next'
                                    });
    }
});
    }
```

Comment: question edited along with  code.